# LazyVGrid onTapGesture navigate to next screen swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am quite new to swiftUI. I have created a grid view on tapping on which I want to go to next screen. But somehow I am not able to manage to push to next screen. I am doing like this:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(viewModel.pokemon) { pokemon in
                    PokemonCell(pokemon: pokemon, viewModel: viewModel)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            NavigationLink(destination: PokemonDetailView(pokemon: pokemon)) {
                                Text(pokemon.name)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        
        .navigationTitle("Pokedex")
    }
    
}
```

Upon doing like this, I am getting a warning stating

> Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused

Can someone please guide me, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.onTapGesture` adds an action to perform when the view recognizes a tap gesture. In your case you don't need to use `.onTapGesture`. If you want to go to another view when cell is tapped you need to write `NavigationLink` as below.

---

```
NavigationLink(destination: PokemonDetailView(pokemon: pokemon)) {
                              PokemonCell(pokemon: pokemon, viewModel: viewModel)
                            }
```

---

If you want to use `.onTapGesture`, another approach is creating `@State` for your tapped cell's pokemon and using `NavigationLink`'s `isActive` binding. So when user tap the cell it will change the `@State` and toggle the `isActive` in `.onTapGesture`. You may need to add another Stack (`ZStack` etc.) for this.

```
NavigationView {
              ZStack {
                NavigationLink("", destination: PokemonDetailView(pokemon: pokemon), isActive: $isNavigationActive).hidden()
                ScrollView {
                            // ...
```